# start vrpn client and listen to vrpn server with ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there,

I find the ros_vrpn_client on the wiki page. I want to start the  ros vrpn client, but i get the errror

```
 /home/dante/workspace/ros/groovy/src/ngadh/src/rosclient.cpp:10:37: serious defect: LinearMath/btQuaternion.h: file or directory  dont found
compile completed.
```

I download the vrpn 07.31. I follow the instructions. Someone an idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147611/start-vrpn-client-and-listen-to-vrpn-server-with-ros/) by [Dante](https://answers.ros.org/users/12521/dante/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-02**:
Please edit your question to contain relevant parts of the code you are trying to compile. Also include the commands your are using to compile and the full output including the error message you are getting.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
If you want help, you will need to provide the **full** output including the commands you executed. Also, include the exact source of where you got your code from. Notice that the wiki page on `ros_vrpn_client` refers to fuerte, while you are using the newer groovy. So maybe it does not work at all.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
(without adaptation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

bullet is not longer used since groovy+, use this [script](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/groovy-devel/tf/scripts/bullet_migration_sed.py) to convert your file.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1